# Por que a Stack Exchange fez um Stack Overflow em português?

Tags: debate

Basendo-me em uma pergunta que teve vários votos negativos, eu vou revivê-la, mas alterando um pouco.

Posso entender algumas pessoas não sabem falar inglês, mas por que, especificamente, um SO em português? Por que não um em japonês ou alemão?

Comment: `Por que começar com português? Queríamos começar com uma comunidade que atendesse a dois requisitos: Um grande número de desenvolvedores talentosos, em que Grande parte deles se sentisse muito mais confortável em falar sua própria língua do que o inglês` Link: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/01/ola-mundo-announcing-stack-overflow-in-portuguese/ Outro link interessante: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/02/cant-we-all-be-reasonable-and-speak-english/.

Comment: Nota: Se você olhar no Area 51 existem propostas para SO em Turco, Francês, Espanhol, Alemão e Russo, acho que por enquanto só. Além disso, talvez você devesse linkar a pergunta que você citou.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A ideia original do Stack Overflow e outros sites da rede Stack Exchange é centralizar conhecimento em forma de perguntas e respostas com conteúdo de qualidade.

Só que algumas pessoas acham que todo esse conhecimento deveria ser centralizado só na língua Inglesa. Muitos foram contra a "duplicação de conteúdo" que a versão em Português poderia gerar.

Mas, como já foi explicado diversas vezes pela equipe do SO, pelo Gabe e por outros usuários, muitos bons desenvolvedores não são poliglotas. O acesso à esta informação e ao sistema do SO estava, de alguma forma, sendo negado a eles.

Então, como várias pessoas se comprometeram a participar do projeto proposto na Área 51, eles finalmente decidiram investir em nós.

Porém, criar um SO em uma nova língua é um desafio, tanto que ainda estamos no *beta* com várias funcionalidades pendentes. Só para citar um exemplo, a busca diferencia acentos, o que não é desejável para nós. Também ainda não somos muito maduros quanto ao escopo do site ou mesmo como tratar certos tipos de comportamento, já que nossa cultura tem várias peculiaridades.

Creio que se o projeto aqui for um sucesso, brevemente eles irão abrir o SO em outros idiomas. Quem sabe até outras comunidades que não são de programação.

Em geral, pelo que observo na rede Stack Exchange, onde há uma comunidade vibrante por algum tema, também há um site em potencial.

Comment: Até tu, ut! SE e SO se escrevem *separado*. Corrigi a pergunta e uma resposta... melhor deixar registrado aqui nos *comments* pros próximos navegantes ;)

Comment: @brasofilo Eu escrevo como está no logo... e como é o nome original da "exception"... :S

Comment: Quando o site foi criado, havia outras propostas de SO em outras línguas com apoiadores suficientes na Area 51, incluindo SO em espanhol e em chinês – línguas faladas por bem mais gente que o português. Aí entraram em jogo pelo menos outros dois fatores: localizar o site para português é bem mais fácil que localizar pra chinês (alfabeto mais próximo etc.), e a comunidade de desenvolvedores no Brasil é vista como promissora, em franco crescimento.

Comment: Um dia teremos alfabetização em ingles tambem como paises desenvolvidos e não sera mais necessário..

Comment: O único problema é que se antes estávamos a nadar, agora estamos ilhados, se alguém postar uma pergunta em português que se encaixaria bem no Programmers, o que fazer?

Comment: @Patrick Sobre o primeiro ponto, então seria inválido criar qualquer material em Português, curso ou fórum, obrigando a todo desenvolvedor primeiro aprender Inglês? Sobre o segundo ponto, se você acompanha as discussões no meta, já deve ter visto que nós não somos uma cópia do SO original. A comunidade ainda está definindo os limites do escopo deste site. E se você acompanha a rede Stack Exchange, deve saber que vários sites (como o Programmers) foram surgindo aos poucos para atender novas demandas. Uma pergunta fora do escopo não é o problema. Se forem centenas, podemos propor outro site.